# How to use Maildrop on original iPad mini?

Tags: ios, icloud, email, mail-drop

I have an original iPad mini running iOS 9.3. When sending large eMail attachments, it doesn't ask me if I want to use Maildrop and fails miserably. 
My iPhone SE offers me to use Maildrop though

How can I convince the iPad to try Maildrop?

Apple's support page says that the only requirement is iOS 9.2.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204230

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure MailDrop is enabled. I don't own an iPad mini but this may help.

1. Choose Mail > Preferences, click Accounts, select the account, click Advanced, then select or deselect “Send large attachments with Mail Drop.” (Steps may vary based on the iOS version.)

[image: screenshot (MacOS Mojave]

This [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6708920) points out that only IMAP email accounts had a checkbox to activate the MailDrop/iCloud option.

*One thing I noticed is it may not prompt MailDrop but it may still use MailDrop on the background if you made sure you enabled MailDrop for that account.*

*You can check that by sending a test email with large attachment and check the inbox of the recipient* . If it shows a preview similar to the one below, it already used MailDrop.

[image]

Let me know if you have further questions, or if this doesn't solve your problem.